# Define x and y limits for regression line in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to plot graphs, the basic aim is:
the graph has two layers, the lower layer (scatter plot) will use the data gathered from public database, and then I will add the data from my study on the top of it. I also added a regression line for my data. You can have a brief idea of what I have from this picture:
[image]
The problem is that, due the different dimensions of the two data sets, the regression lines are too long (full range), which makes the picture look strange. I want to define the x and y axis for the layer of my data, however, I just can not reach this.

For the regression, I use `geom_abline` to define the slope, intercept, etc, instead of using `geom_lm`, which I see can take the argument `fullrange = FALSE`.

Comment: you could use `geom_segment()` and compute the starting and ending y values yourself ...

Answer (score 2):

Use `stat_smooth` with `method = "lm"` and `se = FALSE` (turns off confidence interval shadow).

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty, color = as.factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
    labs(color = "Cylinders",
         x = "Displacement in Liters",
         y = "Miles per Gallon")
```

[image: 1]